# GeoServer WMS not rendering in Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I am very new to GeoServer and currently trying to render WMS tiles on the top of the map that uses Leaflet. When tile loads, it does not load all the tiles. In other words, if it requires, 4 1024x1024 PNG8 tiles, it only loads two and the rest to vnd, or loads none, or very inconsistent.

I think SQL query and everything is fine and when I check log, it complains about error transforming BBOX. However, I have another layer with same setup (just different SQL query) and followed same as it is including EPSG:3395 and BBOX. I did not add cache for these layers.

What would cause this issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: Does the layer render OK in the Layer preview that you can access from the GeoServer admin utility?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: Error including the bbox, towards 3395... which is a mercator type. Might mean the source data bbox extends towards the poles, which cannot be reprojected in 3395? Do you have the "advanced projection handling" enabled in the WMS settings? Can you share the full stack trace if not?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out we have two GeoServer instances running and I did not aware of till now, so I did not get to update another one with additional layer I added, and that caused issue. I updated both servers' layers and it works as I expected. Thank you for all again!